# How can I save user image and keep it in my application folder and display it?

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to display the image in the PictureBox.

The user inputs his/her picture which I copy to the application folder ("Image"). When I try to display the path from the "Image" folder it returns always empty.

`picturepath` is the variable I use to store the path in my database.

```
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    Try
        PicturePath = "/images/" + correctfilename
        FileToCopy = openFileDialog1.FileName
        NewCopy = "C:\Users\nilraj\source\repos\caloriecal\caloriecal\Images\sss.jpg"
        path = Application.StartupPath.Substring(0, (Application.StartupPath.Length - 10))
        correctfilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName)
        System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, path + "/Images/" + correctfilename)

        myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then

            TextBoxPictureFilePath.Text = ""

            img = openFileDialog1.FileName
            PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(img)

            TextBoxPictureFilePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName

        End If
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
    Finally
        If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
            myStream.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) to build your paths.
Your application directory is returned by [Application.StartupPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath), you just need to combine this path with a sub-path of choice to reference or create a Directory there.

You can then combine the this path with the [OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename) (the file name without the Path part), to create the final destination Path (event though `Path.Combine` can combine more that two *components* at a time, but here the Path without the file name is used to verify whether the destination Directory exists and, if not, create it. You could move this code somewhere else).

Note that I'm using an `OpenFileDialog` class here, not the Control. You can substitute the **`ofd`** object with your **`openFileDialog1`** if you want.

Remember to filter the images types you want to handle.

```
Dim ofd = New OpenFileDialog()
If ofd.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.OK Then Return

Try
    Dim saveFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Images")
    If Not Directory.Exists(saveFilePath) Then Directory.CreateDirectory(saveFilePath)

    Dim saveFileName = Path.Combine(saveFilePath, ofd.SafeFileName)
    File.Copy(ofd.FileName, saveFileName, True)

    PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()
    PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(saveFileName, True)
    TextBoxPictureFilePath.Text = ofd.FileName
Catch IOEx As IOException
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & IOEx.Message)
Finally
    ofd.Dispose()
End Try
```

If the `VB.Net` version in use doesn't handle this syntax: **`PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()`**, use:

```
If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
```

Since your images will be in the same relative path (`[Application.StartupPath]\Images` same as **`saveFilePath`** here), you can store in your DataBase just the image file name, then combine the file name with this Path.
Assign this Path to a Field, then combine it with any of the Images file names stored in the database to access the Bitmap.

Comment: What does *if i changed the computer* imply? It might happen that you move the entire application, as it is, without re-installing it?. If so, you just need to save the File name (here, it's `ofd.SafeFileName` or `Path.GetFileName(saveFileName)`, same thing). Your Images will be in the same relative path, which you can read with `Application.StartupPath`, same as `saveFilePath` here: `Dim saveFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Images") <=` this is where your Images are stored, no matter where you move your program. Combine this Path with Image file name you stored in your db.

Comment: i mean to say that if run my application in other computer will the image still be there because it will be the profile picture of the user so when he changes his system and log in will the image be there?

Comment: If you have Bitmaps in the `Images` sub-directory, you'll always find them if you always reference `[Application.StartupPath]\Images`, no matter where your executable is moved to (of course, you have to also move the `Images` dir along with the executable). I don't know how the User profile comes into play here, because you didn't mention it before. If you have more details, add them to your question. I'll add a note to the answer.